# Best performance for checking character

Tags: c#, performance

Very simple question.  Which would test faster? This:

```
var myString = "goodTimes";
if (myString.StartsWith("g"))
  {
  // do stuff
  }
```

Or this:

```
var myString = "goodTimes";
if (myString[0] == 'g')
  {
  // do stuff
  }
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Thank you for the read but I need to run about 50,000 of these in a single loop so it is important.  None of those arguments apply except for the statement that I could test it myself-which yes I can and will, but would still like an in-depth answer from someone more knowledgeable as to why testing a char is better than using a string method (or vice-versa) because this will affect other similar pieces of code throughout my project.

Comment: Then you misunderstood a significant portion of the article. Like Marc said below, the code does different things so you need to be testing identical functionality, which at the very least means you need to wrap the second code block in a check for empty string or it will throw exceptions. Now, which of those methods will be faster? The only way is to test. Also, does it really matter? Does this sort of micro-optimisation really make any difference? Only you can answer that.

Comment: The string is already tested to not be zero length in either case.  Caeteris paribus is the obvious assumption for a question like this.  I didn't ask, "will my program be faster if I do this."  I wanted to know if the string.StartsWith method adds unnecessary instructions in this scenario.  That is all.

Comment: "Ceteris paribus" is "all things being equal", which is an incorrect assumption to start with because the two blocks are not equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They *do different things* - they behave differently for zero length strings, in particular. Other than that, *hypothetically* the `myString[0]` should be marginally faster (it does less), but: whether this actually *matters* is hugely contextual. In most cases, it won't, and you'll have spent more time asking yourself the question than it will ever save. If you're in a scenario where it matters, you'll also know that you need to benchmark with **actual realistic data** to have a good answer. And only you can do that, with your own particular data.

Comment: "it does less" is all I was looking for.  I should have been more specific in my question rather than writing hypothetical code.

Comment: @SeanO'Neil if that's what you took from my answer, then I kinda think you've completely missed the point of what I said...

Answer (score 4):

They would both test at almost the exact same time, for all practical purposes.

The second one might be several clock cycles faster, but ***who cares***.

If you were to write the most successful app ever, downloaded by millions of users, and ran on millions of devices every day, and if your app was executing the above code once a second on each installation, the total number of seconds you would save for all your users *combined* would never exceed the total amount of time we just spent discussing this.

Comment: You don't know what I'm writing, and I didn't/don't know if the difference is only a few clock cycles.  Maybe it's more.  Maybe it's half a millisecond which would make a huge difference for what I'm doing.  This isn't just about one line of code in one program.  I like to learn what the better habits and practices are, and why.  Maybe by asking this question now I save myself days of work by not going down a common pitfall and having to redo things.  I searched for the answer first and couldn't find it.  Sorry if my question annoyed you.

Comment: @Sean "I like to learn what the better habits and practices are, and why. " - then please please please read Eric Lippert's blog post and take on board what he says; things that Mike and myself have represented here in part (Eric says it all much better)

Comment: @SeanO'Neil oh trust me, I know.  It is not more than a few clock cycles.  It is nowhere near anything measurable.  And trust me: the best habit and practice for choosing between two ways of doing something whose performance is *of the same order* is to completely disregard the question of which one is (marginally) faster and just use the one which is simpler to write, or, most importantly, simpler to read.

Comment: Okay then so it is marginal, and yes I trust you.  So why not just say so?  Someone once told me to always use Stringbuilder when applicable.  He didn't think that was marginal.  For all I know StartsWith performs a whole plethora of instructions unnecessary for checking one char and that using it is bad practice.  That is why I asked.

Comment: I think that "they would both test at almost the exact same time" pretty much says it, no?

Comment: The guy who told you about StringBuilder was probably suggesting to prefer it over StringBuffer.  The problem with StringBuffer is that it performs synchronization, so it can be argued that its performance is *not* of the same order as StringBuilder.  For most practical purposes you will never see any difference even when using StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder, but performance-conscious people  would generally not suggest that the two perform the same.

Comment: I will ask you to trust me on one more thing: when we say "a few clock cycles faster? who cares!" it really does not mean that we are not performance-conscious.  It means that by know we know enough about performance to know what kinds of differences count, and what kinds of differences do not count.

Comment: One more thing: four people have voted your question down.  I am not one of them.

Comment: @MikeNakis: I've encountered an app where this performance difference actually mattered.  We were profiling the app to diagnose a a user-visible pause and it was basically *this*.  It was only running a few thousand such comparisons, but the CPU was a piece of low-end garbage and couldn't spare very many cycles to process the comparison.  The change got shown around the office as a "how did this matter!?" story.